# Diffeomorphisms act transitively on a connected, smooth manifold

Tags: differential-topology, smooth-manifolds

> Prove that if $M$ is a connected, smooth manifold, then $\text{Diff}(M)$ acts transitively on $M$.

What I'm trying to do is to take an arbitrary $p\in M$ and show that the orbit of $p$

$$\mathcal{O}_p:=\{q\in M \mid \phi(q)=p \text{ for some }\phi\in\text{Diff}(M)\}$$

is both open and closed. Since $M$ is connected, $\mathcal{O}_p=M$ for any $p$, which proves the proposition.

But I'm having difficulty to prove $\mathcal{O}_p$ is open in the first place.

My initial idea was to take a chart $(U,\psi)$ about $p$ and, for any $q\in U$, take some $g\in\text{Diff}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ such that $g(\psi(q))=\psi(p)$ (that's possible because $\text{Diff}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ is transitive). Then

$$\phi:=\psi^{-1}\circ g\circ \psi \in \text{Diff}(U)$$

has the property that $\phi(q)=p$. But that is not enough, since we need $\phi\in\text{Diff}(M)$. I've tried to prove that there is an extension of $\phi\in\text{Diff}(U)$ to some $\bar{\phi}\in\text{Diff}(M)$, but I couldn't.

Besides, I have no idea how to prove $\mathcal{O}_p$ is closed.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: I don't see how this could be true. Not every manifold is a homogeneous space.

Comment: then how can I prove $\mathcal{O}_p$ is open?

Comment: @Matt:  Not every manifold is a homogeneous for a *finite dimensional* Lie group (in fact, most aren't), but AguirreK is right - Diff acts transitively on any connected manifold.

Comment: @AguirreK:  To summarize ths solution in the link Del provided, the key is not just that $Diff(\mathbb{R}^n)$ acts transitvely, but that given any two points $p,q\in\mathbb{R}^n$, there is a diffeomorhpism of $\mathbb{R}^n$ mapping $p$ to $q$ which is the identity outside a compact set.  In the manifold setting, this tells you how to extend $\phi$ to the whole manifold - make it the identity outside of the chart.

Comment: @JasonDeVito, that was very helpful, thanks!